# Spring Boot JPA Fetch Parent & Child

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have 2 tables:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ProductEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ProductItemEntity> productItems;
}


@Entity
@Table
public class ProductItemEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long itemId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
    private ProductEntity product;

    @Column(name="PRODUCT_RATE") // Unique
    private Integer productRate;
}
```

I am trying to run a test where I am querying by productId and productRate, which is as follow:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM ProductEntity p JOIN FETCH p.productItems pi WHERE p.productId = :productId AND pi.productRate = :rate ")
ProductEntity findByProductAndRate(@Param("productId") Long productId, @Param("rate") Integer rate);
```

I save a product and product item first. Then execute above method to get the product with product item. But I get null result.

Don't know if I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

- Spring Boot
- H2 (`@DataJpaTest`)

Comment: Can you look at the raw query generated by Hibernate, then run it directly against your database?  Verify that the expected data is really there in your tables.

Comment: I am running H2 for test. However, when I debug, I see the entities being persisted as I see the ids generated and respective fields are there too.